# Sending HTML Email Using PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to send html email using php. it is working fine on gmail, yahoo etc. but on my cpanel (Horde Email Client) the text is comming as an attachment and it is not showing any body.

These are the headers i am using

```
   $headers = "From: " ."XYZ<noRelpy@xxx.com>" . "\r\n";
   $headers .= "Reply-To: ". "noRelpy@xxx.com" . "\r\n";
   $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
   $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=us-ascii" . "\r\n";
```

I have also tried changing the `charset` to `iso-8859-1` but still no sucess

Comment: Maybe your cpanel does not accept html emails for security? Just a thought...

Comment: Now i removed the headers and sent again this time email got recieved as a plain text. but i want html formating ?? am i doing anything wrong in my headers ?

Comment: I think it has to do with your cpanel settings then...

Comment: just for fun, try doing 
`$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";` first and then the rest of your headers (minus the last two you have listed)

Comment: Did you try putting a space after the : on the content type line? I think it's required and horde just isn't flexible enough to catch the error.

Comment: Yes to the comments about using a library. There is no value trying to do this oneself. +1, +1

Answer (score 3):

Sending emails is hard, and fraught with serious security problems (mostly related to spam). It takes years to write code that sends email reliably.

Instead of trying to do it yourself, this is a place where a third party library makes sense.

We have been using PHPMailer for years: http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/

Answer (score 3):

It is difficult to write custom code that sends HTML e-mail, especially ones with embedded images or attachments. I have written a class to do this, but once you do, you realise there are a bunch of other features you need.

Using a third-party library really is a better choice here if your core product is not a mailing library. PHPMailer is good, another good option is

[swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)

Good luck!